# Faces of triangular pyramids

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, mathematical-modeling

Let $ n \in \mathbb S_2$ be a unit vector, s.t. $n_i > 0$ for i = 1, 2, 3.

Let V be a triangular pyramid with faces $ S_j = \partial V \cap \{ z \in \mathbb R | z_j = 0\}$ and $ S= \partial V \setminus \cup^3_{i=1} S_j $ where $n$ is the normal vector to the face $S$.

Why does $ | S_j | = n_j |S|$ does hold true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faces $S_j$ and $S$ share a common edge. The altitude $h_j$ of $S_j$ with respect to that edge is the projection of the altitude $h$ of $S$ onto the plane of $S_j$. But $n$ is perpendicular to $S$ and $n_j$ is the projection of $n$ on a line perpendicular to $S_j$, hence by similitude: $n_j/n=h_j/h=|S_j|/|S|$.

[image]

Comment: WOOOW!! This is amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: I have one question left: How do you construct a sequence of triangular pyramids $V^l$ s.t. the one side $S^l$ is orthogonal to $n$, $|S^l| \rightarrow 0 $ for l --> infinity, $\frac{V^l}{S^l} \rightarrow 0$ for l --> infinity and for the normal vector $n_1^{(l)}$ to the side $S_1$ holds true: $n_1^{(l)} \rightarrow n$ for l --> infinity ?